# JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION (Error in manipulating bitmaps in android using multi threads)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-bitmap, android-8.0-oreo

In my android studio project using java I'm using Executors(**Executors.newFixedThreadPool** initializing the thread counts to 3) to run threads that do some processes on bitmaps .

But It **some times** shows this error in logcat and crash the activity.(I have deleted the time and my package name from the first of each log)

```
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:504] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: obj == null
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:504]     in call to GetLongField
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:504]     from void android.graphics.BaseCanvas.nDrawBitmapMatrix(long, android.graphics.Bitmap, long, long)
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:504] "pool-5-thread-1" prio=5 tid=36 Runnable
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x12f40558 self=0xca63fa00
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | sysTid=11252 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xc39f5970
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | state=R schedstat=( 98866144 6027605 20 ) utm=9 stm=0 core=6 HZ=100
E/proccess Bitmaps thread no:2t 2: 20
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | stack=0xc38f3000-0xc38f5000 stackSize=1038KB
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #00 pc 002c6aa3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+130)
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #01 pc 00359273  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMapb+202)
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #02 pc 00355757  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMapb+34)
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #03 pc 002308dd  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt8JniAbortEPKcS2_+736)
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #04 pc 00230d47  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt9JniAbortFEPKcS2_z+66)
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #05 pc 0027a0e5  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3JNI12GetLongFieldEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectP9_jfieldID+584)
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #06 pc 000ce38f  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android6bitmap8toBitmapEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobject+14)
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #07 pc 000cda8b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (???)
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #08 pc 0047b3e3  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (Java_android_graphics_BaseCanvas_nDrawBitmapMatrix__JLandroid_graphics_Bitmap_2JJ+162)
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.graphics.BaseCanvas.nDrawBitmapMatrix(Native method)
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.graphics.BaseCanvas.drawBitmap(BaseCanvas.java:111)
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1496)
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at ir.mytoon.app.MyTest.Struct.Operations.compose(Operations.java:206)
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at ir.mytoon.app.MyTest.Struct.ProccessingDesing.doOperation(ProccessingDesing.java:188)
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at ir.mytoon.app.MyTest.Struct.ProccessingDesing.makeFrame(ProccessingDesing.java:66)
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at ir.mytoon.app.MyTest.MVP.Gif.GifProductMaker.ProccessingGif$proccessFrames.run(ProccessingGif.java:336)
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
```

My device android version is **android O**.
**if I use one thread , this wont happen.**

the code line that I think cause to crash is this:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(proccessingBitmap, processingBitmapMatrix, paint);
```

Any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found the problem and wanted to share , may it helps!

Actually in some where in my code I provides the bitmap for later canvas.drawBitmap function.

As I use an ArrayList for the bitmaps for later operation and **Arraylists are not thread safe** , so when I add bitmaps concurrently some times they wont be added and synchronized. so one of the way for synchronizing ,is using **synchronized block** like this....

1- defining one dummy object .
2- each time for using arraylist , doing this in syncronized block.

1-

```
 private final Object mutex = new Object();
```

2-

```
synchronized (mutex) {
                            myArrayList.add(myBitmapObject);
                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Well i am not an expert yet, but i can share what i know at least.**
I think using java built-in atomic reference `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference<V>` can be a bit helpful since it offers non-blocking atomic reading/writing methods, still it depends on what you actually need.
**The links below might help you in your decision and understanding it better.**

- [When to use AtomicReference in Java.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjf8MHf7efyAhXvAWMBHSUgArAQFnoECDIQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F3964211%2Fwhen-to-use-atomicreference-in-java&usg=AOvVaw21Y2Pn3zBxDHZe_fyD2GGt)
- [AtomicReference (Java SE 11 & JDK 11 ).](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjf8MHf7efyAhXvAWMBHSUgArAQFnoECAMQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fen%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F11%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2Fjava.base%2Fjava%2Futil%2Fconcurrent%2Fatomic%2FAtomicReference.html&usg=AOvVaw1cxYMDwlaT5Zxudv9mEOW6)
- [Java Concurrency - AtomicReference Class - Tutorialspoint.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjf8MHf7efyAhXvAWMBHSUgArAQFnoECDcQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tutorialspoint.com%2Fjava_concurrency%2Fconcurrency_atomicreference.htm&usg=AOvVaw2uVZQqM7SrVjSUdLFidbiC)

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.